# Windows files naming issue

Tags: linux, windows, wordpress, svn

I have a wordpress setup which was made on Linux, now I am trying to take svn checkout on Windows.
It's creating a problem because the person who made the setup on Linux kept the same name for some files, but with different case (File names are like **File_name.jpg & file_name.jpg**.) Now while taking update on Windows it is throwing an error because it thinks the file already exists.
Is there a simple way to sort this problem out?
Currently I am deleting duplicate files from SVN, will rename it and add them later.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is not "quick solution". Think about it SVN has no idea what to rename the file to. I'm not aware of any "auto fix case issues" scripts for SVN.

But you should contact the person who made the setup on Linux and tell them about the issue. They might not know.

Answer (score 0):

I think the files named **File_name.jpg** & **file_name.jpg** under the same directory should be removed in the first place no matter in Windows or Linux. Even Linux is case sensitive, the file names are still confusing.

Comment: Yes for linux they are different files , but not for windows.And you cant help if site is handed to you... trying to automate naming.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rename the files, so they are each different, regardless of case.  You can do that directly on the server, no need to delete and re-add them.  Use something like `svn mv svn+ssh://example.com/repos/trunk/File.Txt svn+ssh://example.com/repos/trunk/file.txt` to do that.

Comment: I don' see any other solution. Even if you has a script resolve all the issues, the best it could do would be renaming the files to file1.txt and file2.txt. You would have to fix that manually as well.